# When not to use the preposition "to"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> I'm going **to** Spain tomorrow. The last time I **visited Spain** it
> was great. After that, I will **go home**.

Why don't English speakers say

> - 1. I'm going **to** home.
> - 2. I have visited **to** Spain.

"***To***" would be a *preposition*, right?

1. **Home** ( *Adverb* as it describes the "going", therefore no need to add the *preposition* = **I'm going home.**
2. What would the rule be here?

- No **"to"** because __________  = **I have visited to Spain.**
- Why would it work to change **visited** with **gone**? = **I have gone to Spain.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because _visit_ already contains the meaning _to_. If you visit someone, you go _to_ their home, hospital bed or whatever to see them. If you visit a place, you travel  _to_ it.

Answer (score 1):

We say (and write)

- > I'm going to the park.
- > I'm going to school.

But always

> I'm going home.

Never  "I'm going to home".

We say "I have gone to X" but never "I have visited to X" rather always "I have visited X."

Most verbs will either take "to" with such an indirect object, or not. "I have listened to Bach" but "I have heard the music" not "I have heard to the music". I am not sure why "going" does not use this for "home" but does for most other destinations. One says "I am going to my home" or "to her home" but never "to home". I think it is simply one of the oddities of the language.

Comment: In which sentence is "home" a noun? It is not clear?

Comment: In "I am going home" home is a noun, a specific place. The question seems to suggest tht home is an adverb here, unless I have misunderstood it.

Comment: This is what [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/home) suggests, not only me.

Comment: @fev I disagree in that usage, although surely "home" can be an adverb. . But given a reputable source that says the exact opposite, i will edit this out of the answer.

Comment: Thank you David. I think we are all on the right path. I got another comment on wordreference. It seems "home" can be an adverb if we refer to our own home. It is a noun if it is someone else's. Ref: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/going-to-home-visited-to-spain.3772917/post-19266984